# How to create a Loading/Splash Screen in PHP?

Tags: php, css

How do I create a loading overlay(with loading gif) while php script runs and returns data

Comment: You might want to tell us about your specific situation. There are about 1000000+ ways this can be done.

Comment: Are you talking about while the page is loading? Or starting the php script after the page loads so you can display the overlay?  Agreed with karim - more detail, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language and what you're looking for is something that interacts with the browser on the clientside.

You're probably best of using a solution involving AJAX - for example using Jquery:

When the user loads the page, make an AJAX call that runs your script. Show a div that displays your 'loading' gif. When the AJAX call finishes, hide the div with your 'loading' gif.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more information as to what to show and when to show the image. but to start with here is [post](http://techxplorer.com/2007/10/06/using-jquery-for-an-ajax-loading-message/) about hot you can show a "loading" message (gif) using php and JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX-like technologies and 2 php-scripts. The first should output only "loading..." div and start of AJAX-request to the second one, which returns the full content of your page.

PS: actually, I'm not sure if you understand, that "loading" exists on client-side browser as php's output, but php script runs on server before your browser gets it's output... read more about how HTTP and web servers work - this knowlege is quite neccesary for any good web-developer.

Comment: for any GOOD webdeveloper? *sigh* but you're right - the mayority of (so called) web developers are like car mechanics that have never seen a motor and no idea of how it works

Comment: Exactly, Schnalle, exactly... that's what I mean!